# Manual LVM encryption setup with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, encryption, lvm, ubiquity

I am trying hard to get ubiquity works. The thing is that I want to setup Ubuntu 13.04 on a full encrypted LVM aside a Windows installation. So I can't use the default option of full disk encryption.

The issue is when I try to use a partition as physical encryption volume I always get an error concerning keyfile.

And if I make the partition before launching ubiquity, then I get an error when I try to make the mapping between logical volumes and mount points.

This was working great with alternate CD (or USB) but since they shutdown this Ubuntu image, I'm stuck.

Maybe it is time to look for another Linux distro or maybe someone has a solution...

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the server CD image.

You'll get a full fledged advanced installer like the alternate installer, but it won't install any GUI. Install it afterwards using an APT task. E.g. for regular Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
```

or KDE/Kubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop^
```

(the caret is not a typo). Ubuntu is just a set of packages and while the several flavours install different packages by default, you can just change that.

Ever since 12.04 the separate *server* flavour of the kernel has been dropped and merged with the *desktop* flavour, so you don't have to deal with that.

Here's the bug report for implementing manual LVM partitioning in combination with encryption in the desktop installer: [[FFe] [UIFe] Manual Partitioning Crypt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1042649)  and a blueprint: [Improving support for LVM & LUKS encryption within Ubiquity](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-q-ubiquity-lvm-luks).

Answer (score 0):

I just had success with instructions from here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsViaUbiquity

Basically, you will have to set up your LUKS container and the volumes within the container using command line (`cryptsetup`, `pvcreate`, `vgcreate`, `lvcreate`), before starting the installer. Then in the installer choose manual partitioning and point it to the LVs you created. The LUKS container needs to be open (`cryptsetup luksOpen`) during the installation for the installer to see inside it. After the installer finishes, you need to manually add the LUKS container to `/etc/crypttab` so that the newly installed system knows about it and prompts for password at boot.

Remember that you need to have a `/boot` partition outside the LUKS container.

It's not pretty, but at least it's possible to do.

Not recommended if this is your first time using `cryptsetup` and LVM command line tools (or at least, **back up any data you want to keep before trying this**).

Answer (score -2):

It is time then to move on then.

Ubuntu installer is broken now. They used Debian installer in the past (up to 12.04) for advanced setups, but now you only have the "unified" installer, made by Canonical, which is simply broken when it comes to encrypted LVM installations. I've tried using my old encrypted LVM volumes, entered passphrase and it simply reformatted them into ext4 partitions without any warning, wiping all my data. There were no option to use encrypted volumes as LVM PVs at all either.

My advice is just to stay away from Ubuntu if you're past oversimplified setups. Both Fedora 18 and Debian 7 do what you want just fine. Debian 7 is being released this weekend, btw.

Comment: Your answer is not very constructive or helpful. Sorry.